# Forward engineer a Workbench model but with my own name for the scheme

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, forward-engineer

How can I forward engineer a Workbench model with my given name of the database scheme?

Yes I can edit it in the editor window shown on the image, but what if I have 30 tables to export as SQL code?

Yes I can use find/replace tool before executing the exported SQL, but you can forget to use it and therefore export scheme with wrong name. I also have to drop "mydb" to keep MySQL clean.

Or is it at all possible?

As shown on the image I want to replace "mydb" with for example "animalsDB"

[image: mysqlworkbench]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to avoid qualified object identifiers (that include the schema) set the option as shown in the image for the forward engineering operation.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. At first, you open your model.Then select "mydb" to edit the schema name.
2. Rename your schema name. Now your schema name's been updated.
3. Proceed with "Forward engineering" as you have done before. As you can see the database name' changed.